# Force the title and subtitle to appear on the same slide of a pptx output in Quarto R

Tags: r, rstudio, powerpoint, quarto

I want to be able to create a PowerPoint output in `R` (using `quarto`, `qmd`) but I've been having some difficulties in the actual format of the powerpoint.

When I execute the following code:

```
---
title: "My presentation"
subtitle: "January 2023"
author: "Me"
format: pptx
reference-doc: template6.pptx
mainfont: Open Sans
sansfont: Open Sans
---
 
# Title 
## Subtitle
```

I receive a pptx output with two separate slides, as shown:

[image: pptx example1]

What I am looking for is something like in the picture bellow:

[image: pptx example2]

**A title, in a certain color (and larger size) and bellow a subtitle with another color (with a smaller size).**

I've tried messing around with the template, but I didn't find anything close to it.
I know adding it manually would solve the problem, but I'm really adamant about keeping this process as most "automatic" as possible.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `slide-level` option in your document's YAML header.

So in your case, using:

```
---
title: "My presentation"
subtitle: "January 2023"
author: "Me"
format: pptx
reference-doc: template6.pptx
mainfont: Open Sans
sansfont: Open Sans
slide-level: 1
---
```

ensures that new slides are created when a heading is level 1 but not for any subheadings.  Alternatively, you can turn off new slide creation via headings by using `slide-level: 0` and create new slides manually using horizontal rules (e.g. using three dashes `---`).

From the documentation:

> slide-level
>
> Specifies that headings with the specified level create slides.
> Headings above this level in the hierarchy are used to divide the
> slide show into sections; headings below this level create subheads
> within a slide. Valid values are 0-6. If a slide level of 0 is
> specified, slides will not be split automatically on headings, and
> horizontal rules must be used to indicate slide boundaries. If a slide
> level is not specified explicitly, the slide level will be set
> automatically based on the contents of the document.

Comment: Fantastic! And so simple, but I really didn't anyway to solve it. I noticed that the color of the second heading (subtitle) appears black, and I wanted it to be gray. Does this have to do with the pptx template, or is there a way to force a color of a heading via `R` code?

Comment: Update to my comment: it is possible via formatting pptx-template

Comment: @Bileobio, if this answer solve your problem, I would recommend you to mark this answer accepted and also considering the extent of help you have got from this answer, I would recommend to upvote this (if you haven't already) : )

Comment: @shafee don't worry, I was getting to it ; )